# How to generate a SQL Command string that is safe from SQL Injection?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-injection

I have a situation where I have to take input from a user, create a SQL command and send that command to a service that will execute the SQL.  The service ONLY allows for a SQL string -- not additional parameters; so I am forced to create the entire SQL statement on my end of things.

***I do not have any kind of access to the database itself -- only a service that sits overtop of it.***

I realize the following is **NOT** safe:

```cs
var sql = $"SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE name = '{incomingdata.searchName}'";
```

But if I generate SQL with parameters, would this be safe from SQL injection?

```cs
var sql = $@"
DECLARE @Name varchar(50);
SET @Name = '{incomingdata.searchName}';
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE name = @Name";
```

Comment: No, it would not be. *Why* can't you parameterise? C# has full support for parametrised queries. What is this "service"?

Comment: Probably worth a conversation with the person who owns the service

Comment: Get the service fixed. Don't try to do magic to work with a broken service.

Comment: If you absolutely have no alternative, `'{incomingdata.searchName.Replace("'", "''")}'` will do it. The trouble is that you have to make sure to do this kind of thing *everywhere*, and the escaping and formatting may vary depending on whether you're passing a string, a `null`, an identifier, a `DateTime`... A single slip-up and you have a security problem. Parameters exist for a really good reason.

Comment: I realize c# has parameterisation; however, as noted, I have no connection to the database at all.  There is no way to make a SQL connection to the db from the c# code.

Comment: Also you must guarantee through type safety or otherwise that any string injected outside of single quotes is safe.  So identifiers must be escaped as per QUOTENAME, and numbers be typed as numbers in the code, or validated to contain only numerals and '.'.

Comment: @DaleK as T-SQL doesn't require strong statement terminating, stopping the use of a semicolon does nothing but hinder good data input.

Comment: Yeah I can't work out why you've been downvoted, aside from the fact that you could probably have done more research.

Comment: @DaleK -- probably not a good idea to just look `;` -- there may be ways to "trick" the compiler with extended character sets.  Better to have an allowlist of characters in names instead of a blocklist.

Comment: [This OWASP document](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html) looks very good

Comment: "The service ONLY allows for a SQL string". This is a terrible anti-pattern. Have the service owner another add endpoint that compiles and executes any arbitrary C# code. That way, you can send a parameterized query ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This is not an ideal situation.  I would try and look for a parametrized way to solve this problem failing that I would test the input and in ANY case where a test fails not allow the query at all and ask the user to re-enter.

Do the following tests:

- Length of input is smaller than a max name size (25 characters?)
- All input characters are in the alphabet
- No reserved SQL words (easy to find with a google search)

If the input does not fail any of these tests you should be OK.  DON'T try to sanitize the input -- this can be hard/impossible to do with international character sets.

Comment: Blarg, if they have international character sets this becomes a nightmare to ensure that the notation character is only used when needed against a column. `WHERE VarcharColumn = N'{Injected String}'` would be awful for performance.

Comment: @Larnu -- I don't understand -- I said ensure part of the alphabet -- that is internationally compatable.

Comment: `WHERE VarcharColumn = N'{Injected String}'` isn't SARGable, @Hogan. It would result in an implicit conversion of the column. So the OP here needs to inject `nvarchar` if they have international characters, but they can't just always inject an `nvarchar` as that assumption can be *very* bad for performance.

Comment: @Larnu -- ok you are talking about indexing -- this questions is about injection so you are changing the topic -- but in any case in your example VarcharColumn would be NVARCHAR and SARGable just fine.

Comment: @Larnu -- a common injection attack is to use i18n character sets to get around scanners -- the data going to the SQL statement does not matter (so speed is non-issue) because they have already compromised the database.

Comment: I think you've missed the point I'm making, @Hogan. I never said this wasn't about injection. Hopefully theyll hit the mark with the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Disclosure: My background is C++, Java and TypeScript/JavaScript, not C#

Would this be more appropriate:

```
SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE name = @Name");
sql.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = incomingdata.searchName);
```

Sanitizing the user data before it gets to this stage, using a trusted package, might also be helpful.

Comment: That's parametrisation, which the OP says they can't use, for some reason.

Comment: This would work great if I actually had the ability to connect to the database in question.  However, as I noted, the owner does not provide a way to connect to the database.

Answer (score -2):

You are along the right lines. You never want to use a variable that can be changed. Instead, you need to use SQL parameters. You can add a SQL parameter like this:

```
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name", "incomingdata.searchName"));
```

And then refer to it in your query like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename 
WHERE name = @Name";
```

Once this is done, when a user tries to change the value of a variable the query will return no results. It should be said that this way of doing it does result in the SQL property assuming the type of the C# variable. There are other ways of doing this if you want to specify the type of the property to be different from the variables type. This is a useful resource https://jonathancrozier.com/blog/preventing-sql-injection-in-c-sharp-applications

Comment: OP has already said they cannot use parameters, and the other answer already references parameters.